# Which Goosebumps books were ghostwritten?

Tags: books, goosebumps, ghostwriting

Including spin-offs and sequels, there are nearly 160 Goosebumps books. Just about all of them are claimed to have been written by R. L. Stine. However, Wikipedia states that the *Give Yourself Goosebumps* series was ghostwritten by various authors. Knowing this, it brings in to doubt that all the others were written by Stine. It should also be noted that at times, there have been Goosebumps books released every one to two months, which seems awfully quick for just one author.

This leads to my question; which, if any, of the other Goosebumps books were ghostwritten?

Comment: They were written by g..g..g.. *ghosts?*

Comment: @Richard That's what we think at the beginning, but then we learn that really *the readers are the ghosts!*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Stine himself](http://web.archive.org/web/20101130135649/http://www.viterbo.edu/perspgs/faculty/GSmith/RLStine.html), he didn't use a ghostwriter for the bulk of the Goosebumps novels.

> Stine has written 250 books, and he is contracted to write one Fear
>   Street romance and one Goosebumps story a month, and a Ghost of Fear
>   Street every other month for the next three years. Largely because of
>   Stine’s popularity, Scholastic Incorporated experienced a 60 percent
>   jump in sales from 1993 to 1994, making Scholastic the fifth largest
>   children’s publisher. As Stine himself proudly admits, "I’m a machine.
>   I’m cut out for this. I’m usually at the computer by nine in the
>   morning. Generally I say that I’m going to write twenty pages. I don’t
>   finish until I’ve done my twenty pages—and that’s how I get so many
>   books done." Although Stine spends two to three days outlining his
>   books, once that task is finished he claims, **"It takes me ten days to
>   write a Fear Street book, eight days for a Goosebumps." Stine works
>   without an assistant or a "ghost writer," but his wife Jane Waldhom
>   does act as editor.**

He also confirmed this in a 2013 [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1p32dl/im_rl_stine_and_its_my_job_to_terrify_kids_ask_me/):

> **Q.** *I rather enjoyed Goosebumps as a kid. The Monster Blood books, specifically. Did you write all of the GooseBumps books yourself, or
>   like K.A. Applegate, act as more of a supervisor to other ghost
>   writers?*
>
> **RL__Stine:** ***I wrote all the GB books myself,*** believe it or not. Sometimes I had writers help me with the outlines. But all books were by me.

Of course, this doesn't take into account that he might just be lying.

Comment: [Kathryn Lance's website](http://www.klance.com/publications.html) states that she wrote seven books in the *Give Yourself Goosebumps* series and two in the *R.L. Stine's Ghosts of Fear Street* series. However, this still leaves the possibility that R.L. Stine wrote the entire main series by himself.

Answer (score -3):

When I was in grade 4 or 5 our school had an author come in and tell us (hesitatingly) he wrote a *Goosebumps* book. I don't remember the author but he had written a *Hardy Boys* or *Babysitters Club* book? (forgive me I was young) He told us that he could not reveal the book he wrote because he was not allowed to say. Also, he had to write it exactly how the other ones were written. I don't know why but everyone believed him. He said that he thinks R.L Stine didn't write any of the *Goosebumps* books. This was a small rocky mountain town in Canada and in the mid 90's.

Comment: *"Unnamed author makes unsubstantiated claim off-the-record to children"* isn't much of an answer, especially given that there's plenty of evidence that Stine did write some/most of the books.

Answer (score -3):

I think Stine wrote most of his books like the original series but I don't think he wrote all of the spinoff series maybe half of them or he works on books with other people like he does half the book and ??? does the other half because some of his books don't have his style say one night at Horrorland compared to say cheese and die they both have different styles like how one is more dark humor and the other is just plan humor

Comment: Can you offer any specific evidence to back this up other than your assertion that the tone changed over the decades

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "I think" these things, but for a proper answer you should provide some evidence that these are true.  Please read [answer].